# "DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: file too short" When running docker image to connect to oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, docker

When trying to run my docker image, I am presented with the following error: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "oracle_lib/instantclient_21_4/libclntsh.so: file too short"`

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install libaio1

COPY ../requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ /app
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"
ENV PATH "${PATH}:/app"

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "products/product_db.py"]
```

**product_db.py** runs the following code to connect to the database: `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="oracle_lib/instantclient_21_4", config_dir="oracle_config/Wallet_pricedb")`
which works completely fine when running linux on my computer and this error is not shown.

I have tried manually setting the required environment variables eg $TNS_ADMIN, $ORACLE_HOME, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the correct locations (which also worked when trying to connect to the oracle database through linux in vs code), but the same error is given when running the docker image. I also followed all the steps of the cx_Oracle 8 installation guide and still receive the same error.

Comment: For reference https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python has some information on using docker with cx_Oracle.  It also has links to Dockerfiles and container images.

Answer (score 0):

- Your error is a system error "oracle_lib/instantclient_21_4/libclntsh.so: file too short" that is wrapped in the DPI message.  It looks like you have some file corruption or other OS error.  How is Instant Client getting installed?  Does SQL*Plus work?
- With Instant Client don't set ORACLE_HOME
- On Linux,  the only effect of `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="oracle_lib/instantclient_21_4")` is to immediately load libraries.  You still need to make sure that those libraries are in the system library search path (e.g LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or via `ldconfig`) *before* the process starts.  But make sure you are passing the same directory as used in the system search path otherwise you might get odd behavior or errors.
- `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(config_dir="oracle_config/Wallet_pricedb")` internally sets `TNS_ADMIN` so it will override any value of the variable

Comment: Thanks for the response @Christopher Jones Instant client is installed via downloading the zip file and extracting it into the oracle_lib folder that I created. I have also now tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the same location as the lib_dir (oracle_lib/instantclient_21_4) but this still gives the same error. Also, I should probably add, I am quite new to oracle databases and the whole process.

Comment: Not sure if this was clear or not, but I managed to get everything working fine on linux running in vs code, the problems are only happening when trying to run inside of a docker container.

Comment: It turns out I didn't have my sqlnet.ora file properly configured this whole time. I have edited it to the correct path and my problem is resolved, thanks again for the post